# Number of handshakes in a party.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> After a dinner every person in a party shakes hands with the others. Total number of hand shakes is $105$. Then the number of persons attended  that party is:

The correct answer was given as $15$.

But what I did was,
First person shakes hands with $(n-1)$ people,
Second person with $(n-2)$ people
and likewise
the last person with no other.
So
\begin{equation*}
(n-1)+(n-2)+...+(n-(n-1))+(n-n)=105 \Leftrightarrow\\
n^2-\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}=105 \Leftrightarrow\\
 \frac{n^2+n}{2}=105\Leftrightarrow\\
n=14
\end{equation*}

What did I do wrong??

Comment: $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac12n(n+1)$ (not $\frac12n(n-1)$). Personally I would go for: there are $15\times14$ handshakes, but double counted. So the outcome is half of that.

Comment: Your sum expands to $n$, not $n-1$.

Comment: $(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+(n-n)=(n+n+\cdots+n)-(1+2+\cdots+n)$.

Comment: Why does your variable suddenly change name for $n$ to $x$?

Comment: There is a mistake in your calculation. There are $n$ terms in the sum $(n-1)+(n-2)+...+(n-(n-1))+(n-n)$ so it simplifies to $n^2-\frac{(n+1)(n)}{2}$.

Comment: Got it @MichaelCohen

Comment: @drhab I excluded n-n, but missed removing that n from $n^2$... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using combinations is the easiest way for solving this
Here,
\begin{eqnarray*}
nC_2 &=&105\\
\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}&=&105\\
\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}&=&210\\
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1}{(n-2)\cdots1}&=&210\\
n(n-1)&=&210\\
n&=&15
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 4):

If you store the relevant handshakes in a $n \times n$ matrix ($a_{ij} = 1$ if person $i$ shakes hands with $j$), the number of handshakes is the number of entries above the diagonal, i.e. $\frac 12(n^2-n)$. Solving $\frac 12 (n^2-n) =105$ gets you the correct answer.

Using your method, the number of handshakes is given by
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)= n(n-1)- \frac{(n-1)n}{2} = \frac 12 (n^2-n).
$$